# Application cannot connect to database when dockerized

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a problem with dockerizing my application:

When I start my dockerized postgres-database and my not dockerized application by simply executing the jar file everything works fine.
However, if I also dockerize my application and then start everything with docker-compose, my application starts but then quickly stops with the exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5430 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Because my application has no problem with connecting to the database when simply executing the jar-file, I think there must be a problem with how I configured the docker stuff.

I created a docker-image of my application with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11
COPY  ./myapp-0.0.1.jar ./app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

My docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:

  users-postgres:
    container_name: ic_postgres_users
    image: postgres:10.16-alpine
    env_file:
      - cfg/usersdb.env
    ports:
      - 5430:5432
    volumes:
      - ../volumes/users/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  
  myApp:
    container_name: myApp
    image: myAppImage
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Any help with fixing this problem would be great!

Comment: From the error message, I guess that the database host in the application is defined as `localhost`, which is incorrect. Host names are resolved in the container, therefore `localhost` is the container itself, where no database is running. From within the docker network, docker containers are reachable through their container name, e.g. `users-postgres`. We should use `users-postgres` as database-host in the application.

Comment: You may be able to add a ‘network_mode: host’ parameter to each of your services as an alternative.  I tend to do this when I have multiple containers that need to talk to each via API routing.  Sorry for the poor formatting - on mobile!

Comment: You can set the `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` environment variable to point to the database container; `jdbc:postgresql://users-postgres/dbname`.  Use the Compose service name as the host name, not `localhost`; do _not_ set `network_mode: host`, which generally disables Docker's networking layer.  `ports:` are not considered (or required) for connections between containers.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation has more details.

Comment: Thanks alot guys, that solved my problem! I changed the database url in my application from `localhost:5430` to `ic_postgres_users` and now it works. How can i upvote your replies? All I see is a flag that I can click.